# load and execute a script in android and ios

Tags: javascript, android, ios, lua

My requirements:

- This should work in Android and iOS
- I want to load a script (could be Javascript or Lua or any other scripting language) from a file (not necessarily over the network)
- The script should run in a background thread and be able to post to the UI thread
- I want to use the same script in iOS and Android, so that I can reuse the script code both in Android and iOS app

What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

[WebView Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) with Javascript Enabled

SFWebView i think in iOS also support Javascript.

Not sure that you can use it in background thread as Android Webview will only runs on UI thread

Comment: I was hoping to do without a WebView. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: 
1. You MUST load the HTML into string:

```
private String readHtml(String remoteUrl) {
String out = "";
BufferedReader in = null;
try {
    URL url = new URL(remoteUrl);
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    String str;
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        out += str;
    }
} catch (MalformedURLException e) { 
} catch (IOException e) { 
} finally {
    if (in != null) {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
return out;
}
```

2. Load WebView with base URL:

   ```
    String html = readHtml("Your Web URL");
    mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", html, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
   ```

In this particular case you should have all .js files you want to use on the page to reside somewhere under "assets" folder of project. For example:

```
 /MyProject/assets/jquery.min.js
```

3. In your remote html page you have to load .js and .css files that reside in your application like:

the same applies to all other local resources like images, etc. their path has to start with

```
file:///android_asset/
```

A WebView would first load the raw HTML you have provided as string, then pick .js, .css and other local resourses and then would load remote content.

Comment: I was hoping to do without a WebView. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In android, While loading the page into webview. Intercept the script call.

```
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
 if ( url.endsWith("script.js") ) {
    AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = assetManager.openFd("script.js");
    FileInputStream stream = fileDescriptor.createInputStream();
    return new WebResourceResponse("text/javascript","UTF-8",stream);
 }
}
```

Webview runs on ui thread. I am not sure that there is way to load webresources from background threads.

Comment: I was hoping to do without a WebView. Thanks anyway.